# Refresh css on toggling 'disabled' attribute of dijit widgets via javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, dom-events

I am changing the disabled attribute of a number of dijits on users' certain actions. Its works but the css of the widgets doesn't get updated, unless being hovered over, or basically triggering any event on the widget. How can I fix this? Am I missing or doing anything wrong?
I am using Firefox 8.0.1 browser.

Comment: What you you mean with "he CSS doesn't get updated"? What does your CSS look like? Are you using an attribute selector? How to you change the `disabled` attribute? With other words: You need to show the code.

Comment: @RoToRa: I meant that the css used to differ a disabled widget from the normal state was not switching on/ off with my code setting wd.disabled="disabled", unless any event was triggered on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing something like

```
widget.disabled = (condition)?"disabled":"";
```

(Actually my code is different but it was doing similar functionality.)

This was caused because the dijit widget couldn't know when the code changed an attribute directly. My bad that I did it directly instead of using the `set` API(This is specific to dijit widgets only, perhaps I should change my question to be specific?).

```
widget.set("disabled", condition);
```

I also got success by doing `dojo.removeClass(widget, "dijitDisabled");` (with a lots of classes for 'disabled' state), but this approach is naive and finally I got the above mentioned solution which is good, standard, and concise.

Comment: Yes, this is most certainly because of dijit, and the key word alone isn't very visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can call JS method while particular actions occur from UI.
I did this in following way :

```
  function disablewidget{
      if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
          var child = document.getElementById("id_of_your_widget");
          child.setAttribute("className", "disabled_class");
      }
      else{
          document.getElementById("id_of_your_widgets").className = "disabled_class";
      }
}
```

Here the `disabled_class` is a class which I have defined in css file with the actions, I need to perform when I want to show a disabled element to user (changing the background etc..)

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1 for unnecessary browser sniffing. IE suppports the `.className` property quite fine. (Plus I don't think this actually answers the question.)

Comment: fixing by doing +1 as my question was not specific/clear enough.

Comment: @RoToRa but what about IE6..??

Comment: @programmer_1 IE supports `.className` at least since IE5 if not even IE4.